# Is it possible to substitute an HTML image with one from CSS?

Tags: css, image, media-queries

I'm wondering if it is possible to substitute an HTML image for one from CSS inside of a media query. When the width is 100% the images that are generally small get a little fuzzy. I know how to insert images via CSS, but I'm very new to learning responsive development. If it is possible, how would you accomplish this? Thank you all I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would start by reading [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's done with HTML. Use [the `<picture>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). You can specify media query for determining which image to load:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

Comment: Llubenovic, Thank you for your answer. I tried what you suggested. I am seeing images on top of each other now. I put background-repeat: no-repeat. I am seeing less repeats but they aren't gone. This is my code:     <picture <source srcset="../img/icon-html2" media="(min-width: 786px)"> 
                    <img src="../img/icon-html.png" alt="HTML icon" />
                    </picture> Then as suggested I put the media query one inside of the CSS.

Comment: Never mind, it's OK. Perhaps if I use the code you provided for the other two images it will get fixed.